# Using CURL to upload a photo to Facebook

Tags: facebook, curl

I am currently developing a page which is able to upload the selected photos by administrator from the gallery to a Facebook Fan Page.

I am using CURL to upload the photo Facebook Fan Page. Yet I meet a significant error which I cannot find a solution using Google.

> {"error":{"message":"(#114) An id must be a valid ID string (e.g.,
>   \"123\")","type":"OAuthException","code":114}}

This is the function I do post request. The request URL is as follow, which has a valid fan page id and its fan page access token (I can successfully get fan page data using GET by file_get_contents())
https://graph.facebook.com/289113764493682/photos/?access_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

```
function do_post_request($url, $data, $files = null)
{
//  echo '<pre>';echo $url;echo '</pre>';

    $file = current($files);

    // post information is rebuilt
    $data = array_merge($data, array('source' => '@' . $files[0]));

    // init and configure curl
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data );

    // finally, send
    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
    return $response;
}
```

I am using localhost to test my code. Temporarily I don't have a remote server.
Shall I know where the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I have found the problem why I am getting this problem
This problem is solved.
But I am sharing my problem so others can solve by themselves.

In my query string $data, I provided a 'place' attribute, 
That is array('access_token' => 'xxx', 'message' => 'xxx', 'place' => 
This is the reason I am getting this error.